# Unable to generate an IRI when using mongoDb

Tags: mongodb, api-platform.com

I'm new to the API Platform framework, and for the project I'm working on we're required to use mongoDb.

I followed the instructions on how to set it up with mongoDb ([see here](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/mongodb/)). But I installed `doctrine/mongodb-odm:2.0.x.-dev` instead of `doctrine/mongodb-odm:^2.0.0@beta` so that the `bin/console doctrine:mongodb:schema:create` command works...

In any case, I created a very simple document based off the provided example:

```
<?php
// api/src/Document/Test.php

namespace App\Document;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ApiResource
 *
 * @ODM\Document
 */
class Test
{
    /**
     * @ODM\Id(strategy="INCREMENT", type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $name;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

However, the response I get is:
`"Unable to generate an IRI for the item of type \"App\\Document\\Test\""`. But as you can see the ID-getter function is there, which seems the be the "usual" cause of the error.

The full Response Body can be found [in this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Cf6zVQew).

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update to API-Platform 2.4.0-beta has solved the issue